# NoActionBar equivalent on Sherlock ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, interface, actionbarsherlock

I want to hide the action bar of my activity. If I were to do it using android's libs I guess that this line on the manifest would do the job:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

But I don't want to limit my app for Android 3.0 so I'm using Sherlock Actionbar. What do I have to do to achieve the same effect on it?

Thanks

Comment: There is an existing `Theme` defined in ABS: `Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar`. See if that does the job for ya. ;-)

Comment: I'll try it and report back. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to hide your `ActionBar` use this : `getSupportActionBar().hide();`
or you can set `Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar` as theme of your `Activity`.

Answer (score 3):

Set Activity theme to one of the following and it will work fine

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar
```